# when I compile, it said cannot find symbol in deque java and I also dont know why dose pushleft contain this line left = (left+1) % queue.length;

Tags: java, object, symbols, deque

```
    public class DequeCyclic implements Deque{
        private int left, right, size, capacity;
        private Object[] queue;
        //Constructing an empty Queue
        //@param s is the final size of the array
 
    public DequeCyclic(final int s) {
        left= right = size = 0;
        queue = new Object[s];
        capacity = s;
        
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return (size == 0);
    }
    public void pushLeft(Object c) throws Overflow{
        if (isFull()) {
            throw new Overflow ("the queue is full");
        }
        else if (left == 0 && right == 0 && size ==0) {
            queue[0] = c;
        }
        
        else {
            left = (left+1) % queue.length;
            queue[left] = c;
        }
        size++;
        }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        DequeCyclic[]  ab = new DequeCyclic[10];
        ab.isEmpty();//this is the problem
        }
    }
```

When I run this, I do not why it gave me that
DequeCyclic.java:115: error: cannot find symbol
ab.isEmpty();
^
symbol:   method isEmpty()
location: variable ab of type DequeCyclic[]
1 error
And I also wanna know why does the pushLeft has this line
left = (left+1) % queue.length;

Comment: Note: `left= right = size = 0` has no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is here:

`DequeCyclic[]  ab = new DequeCyclic[10];`

What does this line do?
It initializes an array (size=10) of `DequeCyclic`s with the name `ab`.

What you probably want is:

`DequeCyclic  ab = new DequeCyclic(10);`

You call the constructor of `DequeCyclic` with the parameter 10, assigning it to the variable `ab`.

Next, what does `left = (left+1) % queue.length;` do?

It `left+1 < queue.length`, it is equivalent to `left++`.
Else, as soon, as `left+1 == queue.length`, thanks to the modulo-operator, left will be zero.

Comment: Thank you very much! It helps a lot!